How to Install a Specific Version of Backstage in a Clean Way?
According to the documentation, the yarn backstage-cli versions:bump command can be used to upgrade the CLI along with all associated packages and Backstage. However, I couldn't find any information on how to cleanly install a specific version of Backstage, or downgrade Backstage to a previous version.
Example: I had backstage 1.23.0 running and on executing the command it bumped the version to 1.25.2. I want to downgrade to backstage 1.25.1 since. there are some issues with 1.25.2 version
Could someone please provide guidance on the command or process to cleanly install a specific version of Backstage CLI? It would be helpful to know how to specify the version and ensure that the installation process does not cause any conflicts or issues with existing installations.
Thank you in advance for any assistance or insights provided!

Yes, if you create your Backstage app with
npx @backstage/create-app@latest

You should only replace "latest" with a older version of create-app, to see the older versions just use
npm view @backstage/create-app versions --json

I try with different versions and these are my results
create-app version : backstage version

0.5.10 : 1.22.1


0.5.11 : 1.23.0


0.5.12 : 1.24.0

So if you want a Backstage 1.22.0 app you should run
npx @backstage/create-app@0.5.9

I hope this help's you
